# Vue2 Variable unexpected behaviour

Tags: vuejs2

I'm having some issues with Vue2 variables.

My aim is to create a backup of a variable pulled down from an Axios call, this will then be used to reset the main variable back to the original values. The main variable is called `loaded_data`, and the copy is called `original_data`.

My issue is that when I copy the variable over, it's passing it by reference, not value. So when I update my `loaded_data` variable, the `original_data`

How the variables are defined:

```
data() {
    return {
      loaded_data: false,
      original_data: false,
    };
},
```

How the variables are set:

```
this.loaded_data = axios_response.response.data;
this.original_data = axios_response.response.data;
```

Reset data function.

```
reset_data() {
    console.log('ORIGINAL', this.original_data);
    console.log('LOADED', this.loaded_data);

    this.loaded_data = this.original_data;
},
```

So when I update my `loaded_data` variable. eg:

```
loaded_data.value = 'this is an update to the data';
```

It's also updating the original_data variable. Console log looks like this if I run the `reset_data()` function.

```
ORIGINAL {__ob__: Observer}
value: "this is an update to the data"

LOADED {__ob__: Observer}
value: "this is an update to the data"
```

What it should look like:

```
ORIGINAL {__ob__: Observer}
value: ""

LOADED {__ob__: Observer}
value: "this is an update to the data"
```

It doesn't really make sense because `loaded_data` and `original_data` aren't linked beside the `reset_data` function and setting it with `axios_response`.

Any help or ideas would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript copies the same object into both variables. You would need a second copy of your object as `original_data`. One way to get that is to use

```
this.original_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(axios_response.response.data));
```

after you got the data.